# What is the Matlab equivalent of the yield keyword in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, generator, yield, yield-keyword

I need to generate multiple results but one at a time, as opposed to everything at once in an array.

How do I do that in Matlab with a generator like syntax as in Python?

Comment: I don't think Matlab has lazy evaluation.

Comment: Take a look at varargout, this will probably solve your problem.

Comment: varargout won't solve the problem if it is a shortage of memory.

Comment: Some related references: [Coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine), [Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)),  [Iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator), [Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)

Answer (score 13):

When executing functions that use the `yield` keyword, they actually return a generator. Generators are a type of iterators. While MATLAB does not provide the syntax for either, you can implement the ["iterator interface"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) yourself. Here is an example similar to `xrange` function in python:

```
classdef rangeIterator < handle
    properties (Access = private)
        i
        n
    end

    methods
        function obj = rangeIterator(n)
            obj.i = 0;
            obj.n = n;
        end

        function val = next(obj)
            if obj.i < obj.n
                val = obj.i;
                obj.i = obj.i + 1;
            else
                error('Iterator:StopIteration', 'Stop iteration')
            end
        end

        function reset(obj)
            obj.i = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

Here is how we use the iterator:

```
r = rangeIterator(10);
try
    % keep call next() method until it throws StopIteration
    while true
        x = r.next();
        disp(x);
    end
catch ME
    % if it is not the "stop iteration" exception, rethrow it as an error
    if ~strcmp(ME.identifier,'Iterator:StopIteration')
        rethrow(ME);
    end
end
```

Note the when using the construct `for .. in ..` in Python on iterators, it internally does a similar thing.

You could write something similar using regular functions instead of classes, by using either `persistent` variables or a closure to store the local state of the function, and return "intermediate results" each time it is called.

Comment: Gah, got interrupted by my crying son. I was writing a solution that would accept a function handle as well in the constructor. Anyway, +1

Comment: If you overload the `size` (returning `[1,n]`) and `subsref` methods on the Iterator appropriately, you can even simply keep the normal `for .. in ...` syntax.

Answer (score 6):

In MATLAB (not yet? in Octave), you can use closures (nested, scoped functions):

```
function iterator = MyTimeStampedValues(values)

    index = 1;

    function [value, timestamp, done] = next()
        if index <= length(values)
            value = values(index);
            timestamp = datestr(now);
            done = (index == length(values));
            index = index + 1;
        else
            error('Values exhausted');
        end
    end

    iterator = @next;
end
```

and then

```
iterator = MyTimeStampedValues([1 2 3 4 5]);
[v, ts, done] = iterator();    % [1, '13-Jan-2014 23:30:45', false]
[v, ts, done] = iterator();    % ...
```

Comment: This works just well in MATLAB R2013b, but `values` is constructed when `MyTimeStampedValues` is called. So, there isn’t really any lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Lumen It's not the numbers, it's the timestamps that are lazily generated here in this example. In principle it does the job and yield in Python is just a shortcut for it. What it does is implementing something that keeps state in between calls.